# How to load an .RData file to AWS sagemaker notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I just started using the AWS sagemaker and I have an xgboost model saved in my personal laptop using save as .Rdata, saveRDS, xgb.save commands. I have uploaded those files in my Sagemaker notebook instance where my different notebooks are. However, I am unable to load it to my environment and predict for test data by using the following commands:

```
load("Model.RData")
model=xgb.load('model')
model <- readRDS("Model.rds")
```

When I predict, I get NAs as my prediction. These commands work fine on Rstudio but not on sagemaker notebook.Please help

Comment: can you try model_path = file.path(prefix, "model")
load(file.path(model_path, 'model.RData'))  ? full example in https://rdrr.io/github/DyfanJones/sagemaker-r-sdk/src/examples/hyparameter_tuning/r_bring_your_own/mars-restrserve/server.R

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Not sure what to put as prefix here? The example didn't define that. I used getwd() to get the file path and then used load("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Model.RData") which gives me the following error,
`Error in load("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Model.RData"): error reading from connection`

Comment: I'm getting similar errors when trying to read/saveRDS with just an R data frame (not sure if this is helpful since you're dealing with a saved model). I manually opened up the saved RDS and the data frame wasn't saved correctly - the file displays the message " 'file' is not UTF-8 encoded. Saving disabled". I'm googling around but not really finding anything helpful. Thinking that RData objects and Sagemaker might not play well together.

Comment: Yes. The best one that works so far is xgb.save and xgb.load. But I am still losing info and hence, not able to predict.